# How to deploy SQL CLR stored procedure to multiple servers

Tags: sql-server, deployment, sqlclr

I have inherited a SQL CLR project as part of a code maintenance project that I'm working on for a client. I'm pretty new to SQL CLR, admittedly, so I'm trying to figure out how it works.

I noticed that the database connection string is stored in the project's Properties, so I know how to change it if I need to. The one question I have though is this: is it possible to set multiple connection strings for deployment to multiple SQL Server instances? In my case I have a local dev machine, a staging server, and a production server (with a separate copy of the target database on each server). I'd like to be able to deploy the SQL CLR assembly to all 3 without having to change the connection string and re-build for each one.

Comment: The question is a little ambiguous. You might want to clarify if you are talking about deploying SQL CLR code via Visual Studio (which is how I interpreted the question), or if there is a specific connection string in the code itself that needs adjusting (which is how gjvdkamp interpreted it). Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not deploy to anywhere but development via Visual Studio, hence the connection string in the Project should always point to your dev environment.

Once you have the code tested in the development server, you can script out the Assembly in SSMS by right-clicking on the Assembly in question and do "Script Assembly As..." then "Create To..." and then "New Query Window".  This will give you the basic script that should be used to deploy to QA, Staging, and Production.

The general format is:

```
USE [DBName]
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [AssemblyName]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x0000...
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

You do not really need to propagate the Assembly Files to the other environments, though if you want to it does not hurt.

If you want to automate that, once you have that basic script you can always grab the updated Assembly code (what is noted as 0x0000 above) via:

```
SELECT Content FROM sys.assembly_files WHERE name = 'AssemblyName'
```

Edit:
For the sake of completeness, as Jeremy mentioned in a comment below, the above info only describes deployment of the Assembly itself, not of the wrapper objects to access the code within the Assembly. A full deployment process would:

1. Drop existing wrapper objects (Stored Procs, Functions, Triggers, Types, and Aggregates)
2. Drop the Assembly
3. Create the new Assembly
4. Create the wrapper objects

Comment: Once you've run this script and added the Assembly in SSMS, you will most likely need to Script out Scalar-Value and etc Functions that use the CLR Assembly.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, very true and thanks for mentioning that. I have updated my answer to not focus solely on the Assembly.

Comment: not really a great answer as tyou can easily set multiple deployment options for DB project, its just .NET projects that refuse to allow multiple configurations. But its as good an answer as we're going to get, thanks Microsoft :(

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy the code to your development server, Visual Studio creates a .sql file in the bin/Release folder.

This can useful for deployment, it requires some cleaning.

Here is a perl script I'm using to get a deployment script from the script created by VS.

It's closely linked to my needs and the file format (I'm using VS 2010 SP1, SQL 2008 R2, perl within cygwin), consider this as an example it may not work automagically for everyone.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Unidecode 'unidecode'; # http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Unidecode/

sub ProcessBlock($)
{
    my $lines = $_[0];

    if ($lines =~ "Deployment script for") { return 0; }
    if ($lines =~ "^SET ") { return 0; }
    if ($lines =~ "^:") { return 0; }
    if ($lines =~ "^USE ") { return 0; }
    if ($lines =~ "^BEGIN TRANSACTION") { return 0; }
    if ($lines =~ "extendedproperty") { return 0; }
    if ($lines =~ "^PRINT ") { return 0; }
    if ($lines =~ "#tmpErrors") { return 0; }
    if ($lines =~ "^IF \@\@TRANCOUNT") { return 0; }

    my $drop = $lines;
    if ($drop =~ m/^DROP (FUNCTION|PROCEDURE) ([^ ]+);/m)
    { 
        printf("if OBJECT_ID('$2') IS NOT NULL\n");
    }
    elsif ($drop =~ m/^DROP ASSEMBLY \[([^ ]+)\];/m)
    { 
        printf("IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name = '$1')\n");
    }

    printf($lines);
    printf("GO\n");

    my $create = $lines;
    if ($create =~ m/^CREATE PROCEDURE (\[[^]]+\])\.(\[[^]]+\])/m)
    {
        printf("GRANT EXECUTE ON $1.$2 TO PUBLIC\nGO\n");
    }
    elsif ($create =~ m/^CREATE FUNCTION (\[[^]]+\])\.(\[[^]]+\]).*RETURNS .* TABLE /ms)
    {
        printf("GRANT SELECT ON $1.$2 TO PUBLIC\nGO\n");
    }
    elsif ($create =~ m/^CREATE FUNCTION (\[[^]]+\])\.(\[[^]]+\])/m)
    {
        printf("GRANT EXECUTE ON $1.$2 TO PUBLIC\nGO\n");
    }
}



my $block="";

while (<>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    $line = unidecode($line);
    if ($line =~ "^GO")
    {
        ProcessBlock($block);
        $block = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $block .= $line;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
perl FixDeploy.pl < YourAssembly.sql > YourAssembly.Deploy.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [The difference between the connections strings in SQLCLR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56801/65747) I think you should use context connection if possible. That way you don't have to reconfigure.

If you need different credentials or something, you can query a settings table that holds those settings. Use the context connection to connect, query the settings table to get the login details and then use them to connect again.

Also: the connection string is in the properties, but as I understand the settings.xml does not get deployed so you'd always be getting the default values hardcoded into settings class.