# SQLCLR execution fails within a trigger: "transaction context in use by another session."

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, sqlclr, database-trigger

I try to execute a SQLCLR stored procedure which uses a `HttpWebRequest`. Everything runs fine if I execute it alone:

```sql
DECLARE @idReservation uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @motif int
DECLARE @idCuma uniqueidentifier

set @idReservation = '52D1A203-A102-464A-8E2D-652B02A2ABDB'

set @idCuma = '40EAB86E-A61B-4646-8AFB-F2C77264E337'

-- À faire : définir des valeurs de paramètres ici.

EXECUTE [BDchantiers].[dbo].[CLRenvoyerUnSms] 
   @idReservation 
  ,1
  ,@idCuma
GO
```

But when I try to use it in my trigger, my trigger can't even run:

```sql
USE [BDchantiers]
GO
/****** Trigger [dbo].[tr_HAB_Chantier_delete]    Script Date: 08/03/2017 09:39:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER trigger [dbo].[tr_HAB_Chantier_delete] on [dbo].[Chantier]
after delete
not for replication
as
declare @chaID uniqueidentifier
declare @rolID uniqueidentifier
declare @cumaID uniqueidentifier
declare @oldRespID uniqueidentifier

-- ID du role 'opérateur de chantier'
set @rolID = 'FA236022-B6EB-4A25-8711-59693747CDDF'
select @cumaID = ACT_ENT_CLEF from deleted i join activite a on i.CHA_ACT_CLEF = a.ACT_CLEF
select @chaID = CHA_ID from deleted
EXECUTE [BDchantiers].[dbo].[CLRenvoyerUnSms] 
    '52D1A203-A102-464A-8E2D-652B02A2ABDB',
    1,
    '40EAB86E-A61B-4646-8AFB-F2C77264E337'
select @oldRespID = CHA_UTL_CLEF from deleted
...
```

I get the following error:

> transaction context  in use by another session.

This code do the http request :

```
 public static void SendRequest(string postData)
    {
        string address = "http://www.envoyer**.com/api/message/send";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        string portiklogin = "****";
        string portikpassword = "****";
        NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(portiklogin, portikpassword, "");
        request.Credentials = myCred;    

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            //string json = byteArray;

            streamWriter.Write(postData);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }
```

Besind this a do a lot of database connexion (the same database who own the trigger/ DBchantiers).

I simply creat the connexion this way :

```
 public static void envoyerUnSms(SqlGuid idReservation, int motif, SqlGuid idCuma)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {

        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=*****; Initial Catalog=BDchantiers;Integrated Security=False;  User Id=***; Password=****; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

        conn.Open();
        int sold = CalculerSoldeSMS(idReservation, motif, idCuma, conn);

        GererEnvoiSMSReservation(idReservation, motif, sold, conn);

    }
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: An `HttpWebRequest` by itself isn't a problem, at least not for a transaction context. You need to post some of the .NET code so we can see what is going on, and why it is even looking at transaction context. Also, please be aware that calling a URI in a Trigger is inherently dangerous, especially if you have not altered the default URI connection  limit (which most people aren't aware of).

Comment: As @SolomonRutzky syas, show use plase some of the CLR code. My assumption is that you you are doing some sort of db access in the CLR code in addition to your `HttpWebRequest`, and that's what causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution!

As @SolomonRutzky says i was doing a db connexion in my CLR code and for it, i used a classic connexion string which creat a new context. I solve this problem when a change my connexion sting for:

"context connection=true"

According to another post ([The difference between the connections strings in SQLCLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801/the-difference-between-the-connections-strings-in-sqlclr)) with this connexion string the context connection uses the user's already established connection to the server.